# What causes a blank memory dump in OllyDbg?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I'm debugging a program right now in OllyDbg, and the entire hex dump is blank. I'm stepping through fine, and I do get the WIN API recognition, but I want to edit some memory but am not able to:

[image]

I'd like to, for example, edit the string pointed to by 00404378 to change the string "Error" to something else (see stack panel) but as you can see in the dump, it's completely blank. If I scroll the dump up and down, it's all blanked out.

Comment: Did you succeed viewing same address from memory map?

Comment: Yes, it's just the hex dump for some reason. It also works fine in x32dbg so perhaps it's a bug in olly